# How can I rewrite this query (it includes UNION, WITH and self-join applied for filtering)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written this view when deadline was coming.

```
WITH   AllCategories
AS     (SELECT CaseTable.CaseID,
               CT.Category,
               CT.CategoryType,
               Q.Note AS CategoryCaseNote,
               Q.CategoryID,
               Q.CategoryIsDefaultValue
        FROM   CaseTable
               INNER JOIN
               ((SELECT CaseID, -- Filled categories in table
                        CategoryCaseNote AS Note,
                        CategoryID,
                        -1 AS QuestionID,
                        0 AS CategoryIsDefaultValue
                 FROM   CaseCategory)
                UNION ALL
                (SELECT -1 AS CaseID, -- possible categories
                        NULL AS Note,
                        CategoryID AS CategoryID,
                        QuestionID,
                        1 AS CategoryIsDefaultValue
                 FROM   SHOW_QuestionCategory)) AS Q
               ON (Q.QuestionID = -1
                   OR Q.QuestionID = CaseTransactionTable.QuestionID)
                  AND (Q.CaseID = -1
                       OR Q.CaseID = CaseTable.CaseTransactionID)
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
               CategoryTable AS CT
               ON Q.CategoryID = CT.CategoryID)
SELECT A.*
FROM   AllCategories AS A
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT   CaseID,
                 CategoryID,
                 MIN(CategoryIsDefaultValue) AS CategoryIsDefaultValue
        FROM     AllCategories
        GROUP BY CaseID, CategoryID) AS B
       ON A.CaseID = B.CaseID
          AND A.CategoryID = B.CategoryID
          AND A.CategoryIsDefaultValue = B.CategoryIsDefaultValue
```

Now it's becoming bottleneck because of very expensive join between `CaseTable` and subquery with `UNION` (resulting in over 30% cost of frequently used procedure; in execution plan it's nested loops node with ~70% cost of select).

I have tried to rewrite it multiple times, but these attempts resulted only in worser perfomance.

Table `CaseCategory` have unique index on tuple `(CaseID, CategoryID)`.

Comment: Try including the execution plan in the question.

Comment: I can't include full execution plan due to NDA (in fact, every table have changed name).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a combination of problems with bad cardinality estimates and use of CTE. With what you've told us, I'd try to give some general guidance. Info you provided on the index means nothing without knowing the cardinality and distribution od the data. BTW, not sure if it would qualify as an answer, but it's too long for a comment. Feel free to downvote :)

There is a stored procedure selecting from the view, am I correct? I also presume you have some WHERE clause somewhere, right?

In that case, get rid of the view alltogether, and move the code into the procedure. This will allow to get rid of the CTE (which is most likely executed twice), and to save the intermediate results from what is now the CTE into a #temp table. Could be benefitial to apply the same #temp-table strategy with the UNION ALL subquery. 
Make sure to apply the WHERE predicates as soon as possible (SQL Server is usually good with pushing, but this combination of proc-view-CTE might confuse it).

Comment: Performance problems are related to join with subquery (was tested by reducing to simplest possible query with this problem).

Comment: @Ginden Are the estimates vs actual row counts in execution plan far off? Try savin results of the union all subquery into a #temp table, it should at least solve the cardinality issues.

Comment: Your idea with temporary table was useful, but I have solved a problem by changing `WITH` clause from `A JOIN (B UNION C)` to `(A JOIN B) UNION (A JOIN C)`. Anyway - big thanks.